# How can I pull a specific set of characters from another font in ConTeXt?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, context

I'm using ConTeXt to typeset a long document, and I'm using the [libertinus](https://github.com/alerque/libertinus) font. However, `\mathcal{A}` produces  rather than a calligraphic 'A', like it does with other fonts. I can get a good looking calligraphic set from either Asana Math or Euler, but I can't seem to switch between fonts. Trying to modify the [example from the wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/math_calligraphic) to use libertinus,

```tex
\definefallbackfamily[mainface][math][Euler][range={uppercasescript,lowercasescript}]

\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [libertinusserif]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [math] [libertinusmath]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]
```

doesn't actually seem to use the Euler font at all, and switching Euler other font's don't either. Looking in the log, there is a line:

```
the requested fallback font 'euler' for typeface 'mainface' style 'mm' was ignored because no files where found.
```

I tried specifying files manually, which didn't change that result at all.

I have also tried making a `\altmathcal` macro which switches body fonts, but that seems to have no effect.

How can I use libertinus everywhere except `\mathcal`?

Comment: The libertinus math font does not seem to have a calligraphic alphabet, and then both `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` gives the script alphabet. The only unicode fonts that have both chancery and roundhand that I know of are lucida, stix two and xits. That does not help you much, though, but now you know why you get what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a partial solution.

```
\definefallbackfamily[mainface][mm][newcomputermodernmath][range={uppercasescript,lowercasescript},force=yes]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [libertinusserif]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [math] [libertinusmath]
```

works for reasons I cannot divine, but I'm happy enough with the calligraphic characters from it.